# ERROR WITH INSTALLING

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,I have this error while installing the ros
mostafa@mostafa-HP:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full
[sudo] password for mostafa:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Depends: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1367611780~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1367578740~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.17-s1367597096~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.8-s1367534634~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1367551894~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1367578071~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.6-s1367550790~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1367612594~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.5-s1367578924~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1367596830~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63531/error-with-installing/) by [eng.mostafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/4980/eng.mostafa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure of setup your sources according to your distribution (See [Installing guide for groovy in Ubuntu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu), Item 1.2). Or if you want to install fuerte, see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu).

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0